# c++ Typelist of derived class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, crtp, typelist, c++-loki

Using CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern) you can provide a base class with knowledge of classes derived from it. It is not that hard to create an array that stores an instance of each class that derives from a base class (see example)

```
class Base{
    public:
        static std::vector<Base *> m_derivedInstances;
};

template <class Derived>
class CRTPBase : public Base {
    public:
        static bool m_temp;
        static bool addInstance()
        {
            m_derivedInstances.push_back(new Derived);
            return true;
        }
};
template <class Derived>
CRTPBase<Derived>::m_temp = CRTPBase<Derived>::addInstance();
```

I was wondering if it was possible to create a Typelist (see http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/ph-jun00.pdf) of all the types of derived classes. The problem is that every time the compiler sees a new class that derives from `Base` it will need to append a new type to the list, but Typelists are immutable (it is possible to create a new list with the new type appended to it, but adding an element to a list is impossible as far as I know. In the end I would like to have something like this:

```
struct DerivedClassHolder {
    typedef Loki::TL::MakeTypeList</*list all derived classes here*/>::Result DerivedTypes;
};
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to iterate over all the classes that derive from `Base`.

Comment: What does "iterating over all classes" *mean*?

Comment: You may be on a wrong mental track if you keep talking about "the `Base`". You *do not have* a base class. You have a *template* from which each new derived class obtains its own, personal base type.

Comment: Also, how do you want to guarantee that `m_derivedInstances` is already initialized by the time you call `addInstance` in global scope?

Comment: In the end I want to iterate over all derived types and do something with them (e.g. using dynamic_cast check which derived type a pointer to Base really is.

Comment: m_derivedInstances isn't actually public and the only access to it is from addInstance which also is private so the only place where it can be changed when m_temp is initialized. All I have to do is make sure that m_derivedInstances is initialized before m_temp. The order of initialization of static variables is only undefined when it is across several compilation units.

Comment: In the real problem Base is an actual interface with many functions to which I wanted to add the ability to iterate over the derived types.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Wouldn't `typeid` work for determining the RTTI of a pointer?  If you do not control the set of derived types, I don't think you use much information beyond the information provided by typeid.  If you do control the set of derived types, you can make each one help with bookkeeping.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Why do you want to iterate over derived types?  I can think of a couple of use cases, but most can be accomplished though by means far more accessible than template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, using a pseudo type-map. Here is some example code using boost::mpl. The explicit definition of "Implem" can be done with a macro in each corresponding implem header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/empty_sequence.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

using namespace boost::mpl;
using namespace boost;


// A type map. Implem #N of type Key is type (default: void)

template <typename Key, int N>
struct Implem
{
  public:
    typedef void type;
};


// Type vector building functions
// void, the default type, is used to stop the recursion

template <typename Key, int N = 1>
struct ImplemToList;

template <typename Key, typename Item, int N>
struct ImplemListItem
{
  public:
    typedef typename push_front<typename ImplemToList<Key, N + 1>::type, Item>::type type;
};

template <typename Key, int N>
struct ImplemToList
{
  public:
    typedef typename Implem<Key, N>::type item;
    typedef typename eval_if<is_same<item, void>,
                             identity<vector<> >,
                             ImplemListItem<Key, item, N> >::type type;
};


// Example code: an interface with two implems

class Interface
{
  public:
    virtual const char* name() const = 0;
};

class Implem1 : public Interface
{
  public:
    virtual const char* name() const { return "implem_1"; }
};

class Implem2 : public Interface
{
  public:
    virtual const char* name() const { return "implem_2"; }
};

template <>
struct Implem<Interface, 1>
{
  public:
    typedef Implem1 type;
};

template <>
struct Implem<Interface, 2>
{
  public:
    typedef Implem2 type;
};


void print(Interface const& i)
{
  std::cout << i.name() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  typedef ImplemToList<Interface>::type IList;
  for_each<IList>(&print);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your typelist can only be created by hand.  The problem you mention, immutability, is insurmountable.

Comment: Lets say I want to create the Typelist by hand but I want to be able to update the list without having to change the definition of Base or DerivedClassHolder. Sort of creating an alias to a list but the actual list can be changed from outside.

Comment: @BenjyKessler - you can't change the list.  period.  You of course can always compile a new one by hand and use THAT list, but you can't replace any already existing list so you just have to know which of the many lists contains all of the values it should.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try to think of some other way of doing things.